# How to optimize count and group by subquery operation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, count

My host is saying that the following query is taking lots of Server CPU. Please tell me how can I optimize it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot,wallpapers.*,resolutions.res_height,resolutions.res_width FROM wallpapers

INNER JOIN analytics ON analytics.`wall_id` = wallpapers.`wall_id`

INNER JOIN resolutions ON resolutions.`res_id` = wallpapers.`res_id`



WHERE analytics.ana_date >= '2013-09-01 16:36:56' AND wallpapers.wall_status = 'public'

GROUP BY analytics.`wall_id`) as Q
```

Please note that the analytics table contains the records for all the pageviews and clicks. So it is very very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot, wallpapers.*, resolutions.res_height, resolutions.res_width
      FROM wallpapers INNER JOIN
           analytics
           ON analytics.`wall_id` = wallpapers.`wall_id` INNER JOIN
           resolutions
           ON resolutions.`res_id` = wallpapers.`res_id`
      WHERE analytics.ana_date >= '2013-09-01 16:36:56' AND
            wallpapers.wall_status = 'public'
      GROUP BY analytics.`wall_id`
) as Q
```

The subquery requires extra effort as does the `group by`.  You can replace this with:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct analytics.wall_id)
FROM wallpapers INNER JOIN
     analytics
     ON analytics.`wall_id` = wallpapers.`wall_id` INNER JOIN
     resolutions
     ON resolutions.`res_id` = wallpapers.`res_id`
WHERE analytics.ana_date >= '2013-09-01 16:36:56' AND
      wallpapers.wall_status = 'public';
```

You might then be able to do further optimizations using indexes, but it would be helpful to see an `explain` of this query and the current indexes on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your query just counts distinct `wall_id` values after filtering via the joins and the `WHERE` clause. Something like this should be close:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT analytics.wall_id)
FROM wallpapers
INNER JOIN analytics ON analytics.wall_id = wallpapers.wall_id
INNER JOIN resolutions ON resolutions.res_id = wallpapers.res_id
WHERE analytics.ana_date >= '2013-09-01 16:36:56'
  AND wallpapers.wall_status = 'public'
```